# Action Not Found in Play Framework for adding new Routes

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have just started doing play framework and i am missing some silly step over here.

I added new route in routes file but not able to access it. Also the CSS and JS is not loading when i open `127.0.0.1:9000` its plain text.

Following is what i did :-

1. Added new route in routes :-

   ```
   GET     /test     controllers.Application.test()
   ```
2. Added new method in Application :-

   ```
   public static Result test() {
      return ok("test2");
   }
   ```
3. Did everything rest :-

   - ctrl + D (To stop play service)
   - `play clean`
   - `play clean-all`
   - `play compile`
   - `play run`

This is my play and scala version :-

- play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2

I dont know what is going wrong but i did `clean` , `clean-all` and `compile` still i can not 
see the route in here. This is the latest play framework which i downloaded as of this date.
play command has been added in my bash_profile and is working quite well.

I am using eclipse for development.

Comment: Can you please post the code of your routes and part of Application.java, where test() is defined?

Comment: It is mentioned above in point #2 . public static Result test() { return ok("test2"); }

Comment: did you try introducing a syntax error to the routes file to see if sbt actually tries to compile it?
And while you are on it :) could you make sure you actually saved the file? That happened to me more than once when I worked with sublime and forgot that it does not save the file automatically. Spend several hours wondering why my changes had no effect.

Comment: I can save the file though but if there is an error it gives the same output . I think sbt is not being cleaned or whatever the changes are not being reflected in any way

Answer (score 0):

The route you added and the route you are trying do not seem to be the same.

- The route you added : `127.0.0.1:9000/test`
- and the route you tried `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: i tried 127.0.0.1:9000/test and this gives me Action not found
For request 'GET /test'

Comment: Could you share you two file somewhere? On gist perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the routes file is under

`<your-application/conf/routes`

It appears that the framework is not reading your routes.

Also, it would try another name other than `test`. Not that this is necessarily the case with play but sometimes the `test` keyword tends to be used heavily for different purposes in code.

Comment: the routes file is under right folder. I have tried another application and named it test2 still no luck

Comment: Can you retry re downloading your play-2.2.1 from the website?  Also what java version are you using ?   Is it possible for you to share more of your code ?  or perhaps the application folder in a zip file ?